# Is there a way to extract all inner objects from a List to a new List

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

For e.g. I have a `List` `A` that has object of class `B` in it and then class `B` has a property called as `name` (`String`) in it.

Is there any way that I can directly extract the property `name` to a new `List<String>` from List `A`

```
List<B> A = new ArrayList<>({B1, B2, B3});
```

now `B1` has `name = "John"`
`B2` has `name = "Michael"`
`B3` has `name = "Doe"`

Now directly from `List` `A` without myself using a for loop can I create a list with all `John`, `Michael` and `Doe` in it.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use Java8 (and you should since it has been released 15 months ago) you can do it easily with streams:

```
List<String> names = persons.stream()
.map(p -> p.getName())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No, I cannot switch to java 8 yet. I need something like this in the previous version. But I like this approach and I had read about it while learning Java 8. Unfortunately cannot use it as of now.